# GParted stop after next operation

Tags: linux, gparted

I was messing around with my drive trying some different arrangements of partition to get another one inside. overall the result doesn't differ much from the original but while messing with it I done a lot of steps. I thought GParted will do the minimal number of operations but it didn't. it just traced all my operations one by one. this gave it a few days worth of work.
As I don't want to loose data I can't hit cancel but I don't want to wait few days for it. Is there any way to tell it to stop after completing the current operation? It's from natty ubuntu live cd.

Comment: An operation like that is *designed* to be atomic. libparted doesn't keep a copy of your disk data somewhere - once it starts, it operates on the physical disk. If you cancel, I hope you have a backup, because you will completely nuke whatever data libparted is shuffling about at that point.

Answer (score 0):

After few hours I got tired of all this and decided that I don't give a damn about my data. I saw that the progress was on 120GB while the operation was to move a 100GB partition left and expand to 500GB. As it is after copying all the data that was on the disk it was essentially copying zeroes, there was a good chance I could salvage something so I hit cancel. after running check volume in gparted, running windows repair from windows cd(it didn't boot without) and running chkdsk the system booted and had all my files. I guess I'm lucky.